# Django method update_or_create troubles to increment value

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django models:

```
class Item_received_log(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   quantity = models.FloatField(default=1)

class Inventory (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   quantity = models.FloatField(default=1)
```

I would like to update **Inventory.quantity** each time new item to **Item_received_log** is posted with matching name. I am not sure if it is right but I've decided to override **save** method of Item_received_log class so it updates Inventory list upon saving:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj, created = Inventory.objects.update_or_create(
             name=self.name,
             defaults = {'quantity':(quantity + self.quantity)})
    super(Item_received_log, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And in returns: 
NameError at /admin/accountable_persons/item_received_log/17/change/
global name 'quantity' is not defined

How can I resolve my issue or come up with better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would have been a lot easier if we could simply throw in an `F()` expression into the default part of `update_or_create` to do all the magic, but the [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25195) requesting this feature is still open.

You can, however, use a more verbose approach for now:

```
from django.db.models import F

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj, created = Inventory.objects.get_or_create(name=self.name)
    obj.quantity = F('quantity') + self.quantity
    obj.save()
    super(Item_received_log, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. There is defaults attribute missed in get_or_greate and expression obj.quantity = F('quantity') + self.quantity doesn't update value.

Comment: Yes! second that if we could throw in an F() expression in the default part of update_or_create - actually tried doing it that way but didnt work. :(

Comment: This snippet work for me! Obviously quantity field has default set to 0